# using AJAX I want to show a message after submitting

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to have a success message in the modal directly below, on the same page without redirecting to a new page.
so I did this but it does not work why?

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>essai</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form form id="form1">
        donnee1:<input type="text" name="donnee1"/>
        <input type="submit" vatue="envoyer">
    </form>
```

The result of the success message rendered inside this div

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#result").html('');

            var values = $(this).serialize();
            var  ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
                url: "php.php",
                type: "post",
                data: values
            });

            ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){              
                $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
            });

            ajaxRequest.fail(function (){
                $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
           });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "it does not work"? What does not work? Form not submitting? returning error? not returning anything? page redirecting? so many things can mean "it does not work".

Comment: Form not submitting,not returning anything i don't find my data in mysql and no message is displayed

Comment: The input tag has no closing bracket. is it a typo here or that is how your code is?

Comment: Your HTML has typos, your JS is missing brackets. Please use Developer Tools on your page (Usually F12 on any browser), check console for errors.

Comment: JS is missing brackets,that is it.thank you

Comment: I want to know,why when I made F12, console give me 0 errors and netbeans show no errors like how can I find typos and errors in my code.